# Reference a specific cell on all sheets of a workbook

Tags: excel, count, worksheet

Is it possible to use data in a specific cell location (example:A1) on every sheet within a workbook? That cell might contain different input on each sheet, but can be totaled in another cell, for example, on each sheet of the workbook. I want to specifically use this for tally purposes. Event happened on sheet 1, and again on sheet 4. But, every sheet of the workbook keeps tabs on the count for this cell.

Comment: `=SUM(Sheet1:Sheet4!B7)`

Comment: Or maybe `=COUNT(Sheet1:Sheet4!A1)` or `=COUNTA(Sheet1:Sheet4!A1)`, it'd be clearer with some sample data.

Comment: Yes. What is the data? Do you want it summed or counted? Where do you want the result?

Comment: Use a macro, that way it wont matter if you add sheets or not...

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub test()


    Dim Sum As Long

    Sum = 0
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        With ws.Select
            Sum = Sum + Cells(1, 1)
        End With
    Next ws
    Debug.Print Sum


End Sub
```

Comment: While this might answer the authors question, it lacks some explaining words and/or links to documentation. Raw code snippets are not very helpful without some phrases around them. You may also find [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) very helpful. Please edit your answer - [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/21428800)